How can I call a webhook when an error occurs in my Laravel application?
I'm working on a Laravel application and want to be notified via a webhook whenever an error occurs. I want to send the error details (like the error message, file, and line number) to a specified webhook URL. How can I set this up in my Laravel application?

To call a webhook when an error occurs in your Laravel application, you can extend the default exception handler to include the functionality for sending error details to a webhook. Here’s how you can do it:
Create a method to send data to the webhook:
Create a method that sends data to the specified webhook URL. You can use Laravel's HTTP client for this purpose.
// In your app/Exceptions/Handler.php

public function report(Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($this->shouldReport($exception)) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            $webhook_message = array('message'=> " exception : ".get_class($exception) ."<br><br> message :".$exception->getMessage()."<br><br> file : ".$exception->getFile() ." line :" . $exception->getLine()."<br>");
            $url = "https://replacewebhook_url";
            $headers = array('Content-Type: application/json',);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($webhook_message));
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
            }
            $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
            curl_close($ch);    }

    parent::report($exception);
}

